# Вопрос по парсингу файла, configargparse

Tags: python, argparse

Мне нужно парсить данные из командной строки и из файла. Командную строку парсит как нужно(а нужно парсить команды по флагу и объекты, к кот надо применить эти флаги), а вот файл нет.
Пример, `-x tests/ docs/`, парсер распознает флаг и две папки(по отдельности, будут строками в списке). Но когда он парсит данные из файла(в файле напишу две папки через пробел tests/ docs/ ), то он распознает это как единый элемент (в списке будет одна строка).
Я знаю, что в библиотеке argparse есть `fromfile_prefix_chars`  и `convert_arg_line_to_args`, но  я пользуюсь надстройкой над этой библиотекой `configargparse`, вроде они там должны работать, но либо не работают, либо я не понял как это корректно сделать.
Собственно, мне нужно, чтобы данные из файла парсили корректно (если есть пробел, то это один аргумент).

```py
class ArgumentationTool:
    """
    Инструмент для добавления аргументов.

    Набор аргументов описан в модуле parameters_parse.
    """

    PARAMETERS_FILE_NAME = f'.{__package__}.cfg'
    USER_PARAMETERS_PATH = Path(PARAMETERS_FILE_NAME).expanduser().absolute()
    IN_CWD_PARAMETERS_PATH = Path.cwd().absolute() / PARAMETERS_FILE_NAME
    DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILES: Tuple[str, ...] = (str(USER_PARAMETERS_PATH),
                                             str(IN_CWD_PARAMETERS_PATH))

    def __init__(self):
        """Подготовка инструмента для работы с параметрами."""
        self.__argument_parser = ArgumentParser(
            add_env_var_help=False,
            default_config_files=self.DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILES,
            prog=application_name,
            description=application_description)

        self.__define_parameters()
        self.parameters_storage, _ = self.__argument_parser.parse_known_args(
            namespace=ParametersStorage())

    def __define_parameters(self):
        """Добавление параметров."""
        for arguments, options in PARAMETERS:
            self.__argument_parser.add_argument(*arguments, **options)`
```

Аргументы из PARAMETERS
`('-x', '--exclude'),{'dest': 'exclude','metavar': '<globbing шаблон>','help': 'Исключить по указанному globbing шаблону','nargs': '+', 'default': (),},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было в конструктор парсера передать `config_file_parser_class=DefaultConfigFileParser`